# wsimport creates wrapper class for list

Tags: java, web-services, wsimport

I'm generating an object which has an XSD schema

```
<xs:element name="roleAssignments" minOccurs="0">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="roleAssignment" type="tns:roleAssignmentDataObj" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

but which generates Java code as

```
protected ProjectDataObj.RoleAssignments roleAssignments;
```

I'm trying to get it generate

```
protected List<RoleAssignment> roleAssignments;
```

I've tried fiddling around with xjb binding for wsimport but that hasn't seemed to give me the control I want.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I needed to use a plug-in to XJC.

I used https://github.com/dmak/jaxb-xew-plugin.  This plug-in will correctly generate the correct wrappers on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried XJC?

Here is more reference:

http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java/jaxb/generate-java-class-from-xml-schema-using-jaxb-xjc-command/

Comment: I have, it's part of wsimport and is used to parse the XSD.

Comment: Could you attach the xsd file?